# openshift: each successful build creating new pod

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise, openshift-3

I'm new to openshift and I have created new openshift app using s2i strategy. But my problem is with each successful build its creating new pod instead of overriding the image on current running pod.

Can someone please let me know the configuration changes to make it replace the build image on running pod instead of creating new pod ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is correct. When you trigger a new build, a transient build pod is created which co-ordinates the building of the new image. When the new image has been built, it is pushed into the internal image registry and the build pod gets shutdown.

In the case of default rolling deployment strategy, what happens next is that a new pod is created which runs the new image. The pod using the old image is then shutdown.

The question is, why are you expecting the old pod to stay around?

The file system of the container for a deployment is not updated in place. If you need data created or changes made by the application within the running container to be preserved across a new deployment, you need to use a persistent volume and store your changes there.

Comment: Thanks Graham,i have memory issue which is sufficient to run only one pod at a time, so every time i have to delete old build and pod manually to allocate memory for new pod creation

Comment: Change the deployment strategy to ``Recreate`` instead of ``Rolling``. See Chapter 17, 'Application Lifecycle Management' in free eBook on OpenShift at https://www.openshift.com/promotions/deploying-to-openshift.html

Comment: Thank you very much